# How can I prevent "" from becoming garbled when I run SQL?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, odbc

When executing SQL containing "" in Excel VBA, "" becomes garbled.
Some characters, such as , do not change.

```vb
Sub DoSql()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SQL_local")

    Dim con As Object
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    con.Open "locald8.2"
    con.CursorLocation = 3

    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Dim SQL As String

    'SQL is set in cell of the "SQL_local" sheet.
    'The SQL is "select test('');".
    '"test" is a function.
    SQL = ws.Cells(2, 2)

    ws.Cells(5, 2).Clear

    Dim aryByte() As Byte
    aryByte = SQL

    rs.Open SQL, con
    ws.Cells(5, 2).CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing

    Call MsgBox("処理終了")
End Sub
```

- When I checked the value of the variable `SQL` in the byte array, the character code of '' was stored.
  The character code of ''.:0xD8**42**,0xDFB7 (UTF-16BE).
- The ODBC log outputs SQL with garbled '' characters.
  `select test('');;`
  ※The character code of garbled character.:0xD8**02**,0xDFB7 (UTF-16BE).
- Excel version is 365 MSO (version 2302 build 16.0.16130.20298) 64 bit.
- ODBC version is MySQL ODBC 8.2 Unicode Driver.

Comment: Most of us could do with some test data to help with this. Use this [Excel VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table or this https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables